# how to get values from textbox which is in gridview Footer c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

like in title  + how to handle button click which button is in GridView Footer also?

file .aspx seems like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="id" EnableModelValidation="True" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit1" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing1" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating1" AllowPaging="True" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" Height="322px" 
        ShowFooter="True" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DriveLic" HeaderText="DriveLicense" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDriveLicense" runat="server" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="country" HeaderText="Country" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWoj" runat="server" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonOK" Text="Confirm" runat="server" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Comment: i have to insert data from textboxes which i have in Footer of GridView plus one button there also and when i click on this button it should insert to database values from this textboxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `GridView_RowCommand` Event you can access the footer control by `GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl` method.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        TextBox txtSomeNewValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSomeNewValue"));
        string theTextValue = txtSomeNewValue.Text;
    }
}
```

Update: wrapped the code in an if block that checks if the `commandname` is what you were expecting. This event is also used for delete, edit, etc, so you might end up running the code for an event you didnt intend if you dont wrap it in this.

Comment: that's what i want to know :) but how handle event button click? because it is in same place than this textboxes

Comment: Place a `LinkButton` there inside GridView Footer, set `CommandName="Insert"` then by clicking the button the `RowCommnad` event will be fired.

Comment: but i have to use normal button:(

Comment: @harry180, sure just set the `CommandName="Insert"` and the `GridView_RowCommand` event will be fired on clicking the button inside footer row.

Comment: ok:) topic can be closed :) i know what i wanted:) thanks WAqas Raja :)