# How to find the value of textbox from the footer row of gridview in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSName" runat="server" Text=""/>
        </FooterTemplate>
```

and the codebehind Code is as:

```
TextBox txtName = (TextBox)(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSName"));
string aa=txtName.Text;
```

Everytime `aa` is `null`.

this code i m putting into the following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Please help me..........

Comment: Where you put the code to get the footer row textbox?

Comment: into protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) { } Event

Comment: What value are you expecting? Null is strange, but it could be converting the empty string to null, what if you set a value for the `Text` property in your markup?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5694274/1073631

Comment: i want the value "which is entered into the textbox at runtime"

Comment: Type txtSName in `GridView1_RowCommand` and see whether you can see in Intellisense or not

Comment: Can you please paste code of ItemDataBound, ItemCommand and design of Gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Try This code it might work:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtName = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSName") as TextBox;
            string aa = txtName.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox txtName = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtSName");
}
```

Let me know if it is working. Are you using this to `add/update` the record?

Comment: but the textbox is in footer row of the gridview          this code is not working

Comment: i am inserting  the record into database.....from the gridview footer row textbox

Comment: Make a command button in footer with command name "save" and at RowCommandEvent make an if condition to check e.commandName=="save" then use this code. It will work fine.

Comment: i have already done that...................................
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName==("AddNew"))
        {
            TextBox txtName = (TextBox)(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSName"));
             string strName =txtName.Text;
         }
    }
but the strName is empty

Comment: use the code to find the control as I have mentioned above. Have you tried it?