# How to get values from controls with in the footer of gridview in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

The solution posted for the following question, doesn't seem to work for me.

[how to get values from textbox which is in gridview Footer c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694213/how-to-get-values-from-textbox-which-is-in-gridview-footer-c)

Here's my grid.

```
      <asp:GridView ID="gridOccupants" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnRowCommand="gridOccupants_RowCommand">
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="15px" FooterStyle-Width="15px">
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="15px" FooterStyle-Width="15px">
                <itemtemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("id")%>'></asp:Label>
                </itemtemplate>
                <footertemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="Server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" OnClick="InsertOccupant_Click"
                                    UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                </footertemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <itemtemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("name")%>'></asp:Label>
            </itemtemplate>
                <footertemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtname2" runat="server" Width="50px" > </asp:TextBox>
            </footertemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </asp:GridView>

    protected void InsertOccupant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            GridViewRow row = gridOccupants.FooterRow;
            string name = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtname2")).Text;
    }
```

This code doesn't pull up the value entered by the user in the text box - txtname2.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What does the code do? Generate exception? Return empty string for `name`? Other?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you're handling the `onclick` event of the button rather than handling the `rowcommand` like the sample you linked to.

Try this instead:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gridOccupants" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowCommand="gridOccupants_RowCommand">
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="15px" FooterStyle-Width="15px">
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="15px" FooterStyle-Width="15px">
            <itemtemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("id")%>'></asp:Label>
            </itemtemplate>
            <footertemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="Server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
            </footertemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <itemtemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("name")%>'></asp:Label>
        </itemtemplate>
            <footertemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtname2" runat="server" Width="50px" > </asp:TextBox>
        </footertemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>

protected void gridOccupants_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).FooterRow;
        TextBox txtname2 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtname2");
        if (txtname2 == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string name = txtname2.Text;
    }
}
```

Off the top of my head I'm not sure where that `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` has come from on the `<asp:Button>`. If my example doesn't work then you probably need to remove that.

Comment: This worked for me now, the only extra code I was:  <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>. Thanks rtpHarry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void gridOccupants_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert") 
    {
        var txtFName1 = (TextBox)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("txtname2");
        if (txtname2 == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string name = txtname2.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your solution?